# How to identify 2 identical geometry and modify them in postgis?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to find a way to identify all table entry that have identical geometry and when found add an extra lenght to one of them in order to distinguish them.

Basically, in table `support_fh` represents all informations about a wire.
Some of the wires have the same geometry.
It means 2 wires that have the same geometry  but still have different `id`.

I was thinking of a function that check for each geometry if it already exists but I have so much data that it seems not a good idea.

For information the following constraint concerning tha table :

```
ALTER TABLE public.support_fh
    ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_geom CHECK (geometrytype(geom) = 'MULTILINESTRING'::text OR geometrytype(geom) = 'LINESTRING'::text OR geom IS NULL);
```

Is there any postgis function that do this already (I've been looking for something but didn't find anything).

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna take a look at [`ST_Equals`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Equals.html). This [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) will probably help you further:

Test data

```
CREATE TABLE support_fh (id INT, geom GEOMETRY);
INSERT INTO support_fh VALUES (1,'LINESTRING(0 0, 10 10)'),-- identical to 4
                              (2,'LINESTRING(1 0, 10 10)'),
                              (3,'LINESTRING(2 0, 10 10)'),
                              (4,'LINESTRING(0 0, 10 10)'); --identical to 1
```

Query

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT array_agg(b.id) AS ids,ST_AsText(b.geom) FROM support_fh a, support_fh b
  WHERE a.id <> b.id AND ST_Equals(a.geom,b.geom)   
  GROUP BY b.geom
)
UPDATE support_fh i SET geom = ST_AddPoint(i.geom,ST_MakePoint(3,3))
FROM j WHERE j.ids[1] = i.id;
```

In this query I simply add an extra point to the linestring using [`ST_AddPoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AddPoint.html), but you can do whatever you want. It also assumes that a geometry can only have one duplicate, as you stated in your question. If multiple duplicates are allowed we need to tweak the update statement a little bit ;)

Result

```
db=# SELECT id, ST_AsText(geom) 
FROM support_fh ORDER BY id;
 id |         st_astext         
----+---------------------------
  1 | LINESTRING(0 0,10 10)
  2 | LINESTRING(1 0,10 10)
  3 | LINESTRING(2 0,10 10)
  4 | LINESTRING(0 0,10 10,3 3)
(4 Zeilen)
```